# Titanium Studio with Windows Phone Plugin: Titanium SDK does not support the Windows platform

Tags: titanium, windows-phone-8.1

I want to do Windows Phone development with Titanium Studio.

I followed https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides2/Getting+Started+with+the+Windows+Phone+SDK#GettingStartedwiththeWindowsPhoneSDK-UsingStudio(Preview) in order to get the Windows plugin. After a required restart of the software, the Windows option apears in the Deployment Targets when creating a new project.

Unfortunately, for all Titanium SDK Versions I have installed, 3.5.1.GA, 3.5.0.GA, 3.4.0.GA, 3.3.0.GA, I am getting an error like "Titanium SDK v3.5.1.GA does not support the Windows platform".

So I basically cannot create projects for Windows Phone.

I am using Titanium Studio 3.4.1 and followed the installation tutorial, though I deleted the SDK path after setting it (it is the default path, setting a value caused an error message, also I left the publisher GUID and Windows Store Certificate empty, since I just want to develop and don't have publishing credentials yet).

How can I create an app that runs on Windows Phone, too?

Edit:
I add some images to show the problem better. In the last step, I don't have the possibility to create a Windows project in Titanium Studio.

[image: create new project]

[image: project details]

[image: windows not possible]

2nd edit:

As per Eduard's answer, I skipped https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides2/Getting+Started+with+the+Windows+Phone+SDK#GettingStartedwiththeWindowsPhoneSDK-WindowsPlatform(Preview) and had to do it. Now I got Titanium SDK 4.1.0.v2015... and I get the option.

[image: success]

Unfortunately, it still does not work.

[image: failure]

https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TISTUD-7171

So I also need to update Titanium Studio.

Well, I guess mobile development has to be buggy and cumbersome, at least that is my experience so far with various (cross-platform) products.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try opening the solution generated in Visual Studio to attempt packaging the .sln   to .appxupload to upload it to the Windows Store. Hopefully that will serve as work around until Titanium has full support for Windows (very likely 4.0.0 or 4.1.0 Titanium SDKs).

Comment: Thanks for answering, I dont really know what to make out of it though.. I never used Visual Studio in this instance, and I also don't get a solution that I could open there. Also, how to install the Titanium SDK 4? I don't get an option for it, only 3.4 and 3.5, googling does not help.

Comment: You may want to download the latest continuous builds from http://build.appcelerator.net then from _Studio_, select the menu item, **Help** > **Install Titanium SDK from URL**
paste the link into the resulting dialog field, and click Finish. You want the master branch to install Titanium SDK 4.

Comment: Thanks that leads me past this problem (and to the next).

Comment: I think I will also need to update Titanium studio, however that works. I will as on appcelerator website, thanks again.